# How to render output according to response of post request made using Angular2

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Currently I have a pop up for login so when the users enters the email id and password and make a server call. How do I react according to the response received. Earlier when I was using javascript I did it in the following manner:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('.signin_form').attr('disabled','disabled')

        var data = {}
        $(form).serializeArray().map(function(x){data[x.name] = x.value;});
        helperMethods.ajaxHandler(accounts_url+'login_user/','POST',
        data,authHelpers.afterLogin)
   }
```

On doing that this was being called:

```
var authHelpers = {    
    afterLogin : function(response){
    $('.signin_form').removeAttr('disabled')

    if(response.message!=undefined){
        if(typeof response.message.validation!='undefined'
         && response.message.validation.indexOf('verifi')!='-1'){
             $('.error_display').html('<div>Error</div>')

        }else{
            $('.error_display').text(response.message.validation)

        }
        $('input[name="password"]').val('')
        return;
    }
    if(response.token!=''){
       localStorage.setItem('jwt_token',response.token)
       window.location.reload()
    }

}
}
```

How can I implement the same using angular2 and Typescript?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Angular2 `http` client to issue the POST request and the `Observable` `subscribe` method to elaborate the response.

Here an example of service class issuing the POST command

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Environment} from '../settings/environment.service';
import {BackEndService} from '../app/backEnd.service';

@Injectable()
export class BackEndRestService extends BackEndService {

    constructor(private _http: Http, private _environment: Environment) {
        super();
    }

    authorize(inAccessCode: string) {
        let myUrl = this._environment.baseRestServicesUrl + 'authorize';
        let options = this.getOpionsForPost();
        let jsonString = JSON.stringify({_accessCode: inAccessCode});
        return this._http.post(myUrl, jsonString, options)
                                .catch(this.handleError)
    }

private handleError (error: Response) {
    return Observable.throw(errorText || 'Server error');
}

    private getOpionsForPost() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    }
}
```

Here is the code that calls the service

```
this._backEndService.authorize(this._user.accessCode)
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        let retJson = data.json();
                        if (retJson.code == 'OK') {  // do stuff
                            } else {
                                // manage the situation when the server responds KO
                    },
                    err => {
                        // manage errors;
                    },
                    () => console.log('Authorization Complete')
                );
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I am able to call the server my problem is know I dont know how to use angular2 to do this --> http://dpaste.com/1WW1DYV

Comment: If I understad correctly your point, you should look at the object which I called `retJson`; in that object you should find your `message` and `token` (namely `retJson.message` and `retJson.token`). Actually I do not grasp the reason for `window.location.reload()`